# Raspberry Pi and Hires Flac files

Tags: raspbmc

Can Raspberry Pi read HiRes (24/96) Flac files and provide HiRes (29/96) output through its USB ports for onward conversion by a USB/SPDIF unit?

Comment: Not a full answer but [low key network flac player using mpd and raspberry pi](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=18270) describes a system which appears very similar to what you describe.

Answer (score 1):

No it cannot. It's hardware limited. There could be a solution to get SPDIF out but requires desoldering and resoldering the pin outs afaik. There are threads on this in the RPi forum.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and welcome to the StackExchange community :) Could you provide some of the links you are talking about?